# How Can I Copy a JLabel From One Panel To Another While Swapping The Image?

Tags: java, swing

I have the following layout...

[image]

What I would like to do ideally is, when a user clicks on a JLabel in the scrolling panel on the bottom right, attach a different version of the image (one without the costs and name) to the mouse cursor.  Then when the user clicks inside the giant floor plan panel, it places a copy of a JLabel using the swapped image each time they click.  When another label is selected the same thing happens.  When they push the selection button (Hand Icon) or press ESC the label is unselected.

Here is the code I currently have unmodified...

```
// =================================================================
//  Restaurant Builder - Interface
//  CSC - 540
//  10/22/13
//  Kris Purdy, Chris Fletemier
// =================================================================

package layout.manager;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    // Class variables
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1366;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 700;
    private static final int FLOORPLAN_WIDTH = 1150;
    private static final int FLOORPLAN_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    private static final int BUTTONS_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH - FLOORPLAN_WIDTH;
    private static final int BUTTONS_HEIGHT = 280;
    private static final int OBJECTLIST_WIDTH = BUTTONS_WIDTH;
    private static final int OBJECTLIST_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT - BUTTONS_HEIGHT;
    private static final int BTN_WIDTH = 50;
    private static final int BTN_HEIGHT = 50;
    private static final int LABELS_WIDTH = 180;
    private static final int LABELS_HEIGHT = 50;
    private static final int OBJECT_WIDTH = 180;
    private static final int OBJECT_HEIGHT = 225;

    private final Floorplan floorplan;
    private Estimate estimate;

    private final ImageIcon leftRotateImg;
    private final ImageIcon rightRotateImg;
    private final ImageIcon upImg;
    private final ImageIcon downImg;
    private final ImageIcon leftImg;
    private final ImageIcon rightImg;
    private final ImageIcon costImg;
    private final ImageIcon deleteImg;
    private final ImageIcon selectionImg;
    private final ImageIcon clearLayoutImg;
    private final ImageIcon hostessPodiumImg;
    private final ImageIcon roundTableImg;
    private final ImageIcon squareTableImg;
    private final ImageIcon rectangularTableImg;
    private final ImageIcon tableForTwoImg;
    private final ImageIcon boothImg;
    private final ImageIcon buffettBarImg;
    private final ImageIcon toiletPaperDispenserImg;
    private final ImageIcon toiletImg;
    private final ImageIcon towelDispenserImg;
    private final ImageIcon wasteBasketImg;
    private final ImageIcon bathroomSinkImg;
    private final ImageIcon ovenImg;
    private final ImageIcon rangeImg;
    private final ImageIcon counterTopImg;
    private final ImageIcon fridgeImg;
    private final ImageIcon freezerImg;
    private final ImageIcon kitchenSinkImg;
    private final ImageIcon dishwasherImg;
    private final ImageIcon kitchenImg;
    private final ImageIcon diningroomImg;
    private final ImageIcon bathroomImg;  

    private final JButton leftRotateBtn;
    private final JButton rightRotateBtn;
    private final JButton upBtn;
    private final JButton downBtn;
    private final JButton leftBtn;
    private final JButton rightBtn;
    private final JButton costBtn;
    private final JButton deleteBtn;
    private final JButton selectBtn;
    private final JButton clearLayoutBtn;

    private final JPanel buttons;
    private final JPanel objectlist;
    private final JPanel whitespace;

    private final JLabel kitchenLbl;
    private final JLabel diningroomLbl;
    private final JLabel bathroomLbl;

    private final RLabel hostessPodiumLbl;
    private final RLabel roundTableLbl;
    private final RLabel squareTableLbl;
    private final RLabel rectangularTableLbl;
    private final RLabel tableForTwoLbl;
    private final RLabel boothLbl;
    private final RLabel buffettBarLbl;
    private final RLabel toiletPaperDispenserLbl;
    private final RLabel toiletLbl;
    private final RLabel towelDispenserLbl;
    private final RLabel wasteBasketLbl;
    private final RLabel bathroomSinkLbl;
    private final RLabel ovenLbl;
    private final RLabel rangeLbl;
    private final RLabel counterTopLbl;
    private final RLabel fridgeLbl;
    private final RLabel freezerLbl;
    private final RLabel kitchenSinkLbl;
    private final RLabel dishwasherLbl;    

    private final JLabel recttabLbl;  // Can remove later

    private final JScrollPane scroll;
    private final RestaurantObject recttab;
    private ArrayList<RestaurantObject> list;

    // Default Constructor
    public Interface() throws IOException
    {
    //---------------------------------------------------------------MAIN WINDOW

        // Create and set up the main window
        setTitle("Restaurant Builder");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);

    //------------------------------------------------------------MOUSE LISTENER

        MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Released!");}

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Pressed!");}

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Exited!");}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Entered!");}

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
            {

               if (e.getSource() == hostessPodiumLbl)
               {
                   removeFocus();
                   hostessPodiumLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   hostessPodiumLbl.setFocus(true);
               }
               else if (e.getSource() == roundTableLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   roundTableLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   roundTableLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == squareTableLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   squareTableLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   squareTableLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == rectangularTableLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   rectangularTableLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   rectangularTableLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == tableForTwoLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   tableForTwoLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   tableForTwoLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == boothLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   boothLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   boothLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == buffettBarLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   buffettBarLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   buffettBarLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == toiletPaperDispenserLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   toiletPaperDispenserLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   toiletPaperDispenserLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == toiletLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   toiletLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   toiletLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == towelDispenserLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   towelDispenserLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   towelDispenserLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == wasteBasketLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   wasteBasketLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   wasteBasketLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == bathroomSinkLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   bathroomSinkLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   bathroomSinkLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == ovenLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   ovenLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   ovenLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == rangeLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   rangeLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   rangeLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == counterTopLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   counterTopLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   counterTopLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == fridgeLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   fridgeLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   fridgeLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == freezerLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   freezerLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   freezerLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == kitchenSinkLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   kitchenSinkLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   kitchenSinkLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
               else if (e.getSource() == dishwasherLbl)
                {
                   removeFocus();
                   dishwasherLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
                   dishwasherLbl.setFocus(true);                    
                }
            }
        };

    //-----------------------------------------------------------FLOORPLAN PANEL

        // Create the floorplan panel
        floorplan = new Floorplan("resources/floorplanPic.png",
                FLOORPLAN_WIDTH, FLOORPLAN_HEIGHT);
        floorplan.setBounds(0, 0, FLOORPLAN_WIDTH, FLOORPLAN_HEIGHT);
        floorplan.setLayout(null);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------TEST

        recttab = new RestaurantObject("RectangularTable");

        recttabLbl = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon testImg = new ImageIcon(recttab.getImgPath());
        recttabLbl.setIcon(testImg);
        recttabLbl.setBounds(500, 200, recttab.getImgWidth(), recttab.getImgHeight());
        recttabLbl.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        //recttabLbl.setFocusable(true);
        //recttabLbl.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
        //recttabLbl.grabFocus();
        floorplan.add(recttabLbl);

        ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover();
        cm.registerComponent(recttabLbl);
        recttabLbl.addMouseListener(ml);

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------END TEST

    //-------------------------------------------------------------BUTTONS PANEL

        // Create the buttons panel
        buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.setLayout(null);
        buttons.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        buttons.setBounds(FLOORPLAN_WIDTH, 0, BUTTONS_WIDTH, BUTTONS_HEIGHT);

        // Create images for the buttons
        leftRotateImg = new ImageIcon("RotateLeft.png");
        rightRotateImg = new ImageIcon("RotateRight.png");
        upImg = new ImageIcon("Up.png");
        downImg = new ImageIcon("Down.png");
        leftImg = new ImageIcon("Left.png");
        rightImg = new ImageIcon("Right.png");
        costImg = new ImageIcon("Cost.png");
        deleteImg = new ImageIcon("Delete.png");
        selectionImg = new ImageIcon("Selection.png");
        clearLayoutImg = new ImageIcon("ClearLayout.png");

        // Create the buttons
        leftRotateBtn = new JButton(leftRotateImg);
        leftRotateBtn.setToolTipText("Rotate to the left.");
        leftRotateBtn.addActionListener(this);
        rightRotateBtn = new JButton(rightRotateImg);
        rightRotateBtn.setToolTipText("Rotate to the Right.");
        rightRotateBtn.addActionListener(this);
        upBtn = new JButton(upImg);
        upBtn.setToolTipText("Move the object up.");
        upBtn.addActionListener(this);
        downBtn = new JButton(downImg);
        downBtn.setToolTipText("Move the object down.");
        downBtn.addActionListener(this);
        leftBtn = new JButton(leftImg);
        leftBtn.setToolTipText("Move the object to the left.");
        leftBtn.addActionListener(this);
        rightBtn = new JButton(rightImg);
        rightBtn.setToolTipText("Move the object to the right.");
        rightBtn.addActionListener(this);
        costBtn = new JButton(costImg);
        costBtn.setToolTipText("Show the current costs for the materials "
                + "and labor.");
        costBtn.addActionListener(this);
        deleteBtn = new JButton(deleteImg);
        deleteBtn.setToolTipText("Delete the object.");
        deleteBtn.addActionListener(this);
        selectBtn = new JButton(selectionImg);
        selectBtn.setToolTipText("Deselects and changes to the select cursor.");
        selectBtn.addActionListener(this);
        clearLayoutBtn = new JButton(clearLayoutImg);
        clearLayoutBtn.setToolTipText("Removes all objects from the layout.");
        clearLayoutBtn.addActionListener(this);

        // Set the location and size of the buttons
        leftRotateBtn.setBounds(25, 25, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);
        upBtn.setBounds(85, 25, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);
        rightRotateBtn.setBounds(145, 25, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);
        leftBtn.setBounds(25, 85, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);
        costBtn.setBounds(85, 85, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);
        rightBtn.setBounds(145, 85, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);
        selectBtn.setBounds(25, 145, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);
        downBtn.setBounds(85, 145, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);
        deleteBtn.setBounds(145, 145, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);
        clearLayoutBtn.setBounds(25, 205, BTN_WIDTH * 3 + 20, BTN_HEIGHT);

        // Add the buttons to the panel
        buttons.add(leftRotateBtn);
        buttons.add(upBtn);
        buttons.add(rightRotateBtn);
        buttons.add(leftBtn);
        buttons.add(costBtn);
        buttons.add(rightBtn);
        buttons.add(selectBtn);
        buttons.add(downBtn);
        buttons.add(deleteBtn);
        buttons.add(clearLayoutBtn);

    //----------------------------------------------------------OBJECTLIST PANEL

        // Create objectlist panel
        objectlist = new JPanel();
        objectlist.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        objectlist.setLayout(new BoxLayout(objectlist, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        // Create labels to store images of the objects
        hostessPodiumLbl = new RLabel();
        hostessPodiumLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        roundTableLbl = new RLabel();
        roundTableLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        squareTableLbl = new RLabel();
        squareTableLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        rectangularTableLbl = new RLabel();
        rectangularTableLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        tableForTwoLbl = new RLabel();
        tableForTwoLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        boothLbl = new RLabel();
        boothLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        buffettBarLbl = new RLabel();
        buffettBarLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        toiletPaperDispenserLbl = new RLabel();
        toiletPaperDispenserLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        toiletLbl = new RLabel();
        toiletLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        towelDispenserLbl = new RLabel();
        towelDispenserLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        wasteBasketLbl = new RLabel();
        wasteBasketLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        bathroomSinkLbl = new RLabel();
        bathroomSinkLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        ovenLbl = new RLabel();
        ovenLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        rangeLbl = new RLabel();
        rangeLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        counterTopLbl = new RLabel();
        counterTopLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        fridgeLbl = new RLabel();
        fridgeLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        freezerLbl = new RLabel();
        freezerLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        kitchenSinkLbl = new RLabel();
        kitchenSinkLbl.addMouseListener(ml);
        dishwasherLbl = new RLabel();
        dishwasherLbl.addMouseListener(ml);

        kitchenLbl = new JLabel();
        diningroomLbl = new JLabel();
        bathroomLbl = new JLabel();

        // Load the images for the objects
        hostessPodiumImg = new ImageIcon("scrlHostessPodium.png");
        roundTableImg = new ImageIcon("scrlRoundTable.png");
        squareTableImg = new ImageIcon("scrlSquareTable.png");
        rectangularTableImg = new ImageIcon("scrlRectangularTable.png");
        tableForTwoImg = new ImageIcon("scrlTableForTwo.png");
        boothImg = new ImageIcon("scrlBooth.png");
        buffettBarImg = new ImageIcon("scrlBuffettBar.png");
        toiletPaperDispenserImg = new ImageIcon("scrlToiletPaper.png");
        toiletImg = new ImageIcon("scrlToilet.png");
        towelDispenserImg = new ImageIcon("scrlTowelDispenser.png");
        wasteBasketImg = new ImageIcon("scrlWasteBasket.png");
        bathroomSinkImg = new ImageIcon("scrlBathroomSink.png");
        ovenImg = new ImageIcon("scrlOven.png");
        rangeImg = new ImageIcon("scrlRange.png");
        counterTopImg = new ImageIcon("scrlCountertop.png");
        fridgeImg = new ImageIcon("scrlFridge.png");
        freezerImg = new ImageIcon("scrlFreezer.png");
        kitchenSinkImg = new ImageIcon("scrlKitchenSink.png");
        dishwasherImg = new ImageIcon("scrlDishwasher.png");
        kitchenImg = new ImageIcon("Kitchen.png");
        diningroomImg = new ImageIcon("DiningRoom.png");
        bathroomImg = new ImageIcon("Bathroom.png");

        // Attach the images to the labels
        hostessPodiumLbl.setIcon(hostessPodiumImg);
        roundTableLbl.setIcon(roundTableImg);
        squareTableLbl.setIcon(squareTableImg);
        rectangularTableLbl.setIcon(rectangularTableImg);
        tableForTwoLbl.setIcon(tableForTwoImg);
        boothLbl.setIcon(boothImg);
        buffettBarLbl.setIcon(buffettBarImg);
        toiletPaperDispenserLbl.setIcon(toiletPaperDispenserImg);
        toiletLbl.setIcon(toiletImg);
        towelDispenserLbl.setIcon(towelDispenserImg);
        wasteBasketLbl.setIcon(wasteBasketImg);
        bathroomSinkLbl.setIcon(bathroomSinkImg);
        ovenLbl.setIcon(ovenImg);
        rangeLbl.setIcon(rangeImg);
        counterTopLbl.setIcon(counterTopImg);
        fridgeLbl.setIcon(fridgeImg);
        freezerLbl.setIcon(freezerImg);
        kitchenSinkLbl.setIcon(kitchenSinkImg);
        dishwasherLbl.setIcon(dishwasherImg);

        kitchenLbl.setIcon(kitchenImg);
        diningroomLbl.setIcon(diningroomImg);
        bathroomLbl.setIcon(bathroomImg);

        // Add all the images to the panel
        objectlist.add(diningroomLbl);
        objectlist.add(hostessPodiumLbl);
        objectlist.add(roundTableLbl);
        objectlist.add(squareTableLbl);
        objectlist.add(rectangularTableLbl);
        objectlist.add(boothLbl);
        objectlist.add(bathroomLbl);
        objectlist.add(toiletPaperDispenserLbl);
        objectlist.add(toiletLbl);
        objectlist.add(towelDispenserLbl);
        objectlist.add(wasteBasketLbl);
        objectlist.add(bathroomSinkLbl);
        objectlist.add(kitchenLbl);
        objectlist.add(ovenLbl);
        objectlist.add(rangeLbl);
        objectlist.add(counterTopLbl);
        objectlist.add(fridgeLbl);
        objectlist.add(freezerLbl);
        objectlist.add(kitchenSinkLbl);
        objectlist.add(dishwasherLbl);

        // Create a scroll bar for the objectlist panel
        scroll = new JScrollPane(objectlist);
        scroll.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scroll.setBorder(null);
        scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
        scroll.setBounds(FLOORPLAN_WIDTH + 25, BUTTONS_HEIGHT, 
                OBJECTLIST_WIDTH - 25, OBJECTLIST_HEIGHT);

    //----------------------------------------------------------WHITESPACE PANEL 

        // Create a panel to add some white space
        whitespace = new JPanel();
        whitespace.setBounds(FLOORPLAN_WIDTH, BUTTONS_HEIGHT, 25, OBJECTLIST_HEIGHT);
        whitespace.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    //---------------------------------------------------------------MAIN WINDOW

        // Display the main window
        add(floorplan);
        add(buttons);
        add(scroll);
        add(whitespace);
        setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);  
        setVisible(true); 
        setResizable(false);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------ACTION LISTENER
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        int x, y, imgW, imgH;
        x = recttab.getX();
        y = recttab.getY();
        imgW = recttab.getImgWidth();
        imgH = recttab.getImgHeight();

        if (e.getSource() == leftRotateBtn)
        {
            System.out.println("leftRotateBtn");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == upBtn)
        {
            if (y > 5)
            {
                y -= 5;
                recttab.setY(y);
                recttabLbl.setBounds(x, y, imgW, imgH);
            }

        }
        else if (e.getSource() == rightRotateBtn)
        {
            System.out.println("rightRotateBtn");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == leftBtn)
        {
            if (x > 5)
            {
                x -= 5;
                recttab.setX(x);
                recttabLbl.setBounds(x, y, imgW, imgH);
            }
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == costBtn)
        {
            estimate = new Estimate();
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == rightBtn)
        {
            if (x < (FLOORPLAN_WIDTH - recttab.getImgWidth() - 5))
            {
                x += 5;
                recttab.setX(x);
                recttabLbl.setBounds(x, y, imgW, imgH);
            }
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == selectBtn)
        {
            removeFocus();
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == downBtn)
        {
            if (y < (SCREEN_HEIGHT - recttab.getImgHeight() - 5))
            {
                y += 5;
                recttab.setY(y);
                recttabLbl.setBounds(x, y, imgW, imgH);
            }
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == deleteBtn)
        {
            System.out.println("deleteBtn");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == clearLayoutBtn)
        {
            System.out.println("clearLayoutBtn");
        }    
    }

    // New label class to allow lables to have focus
    private class RLabel extends JLabel{
        private boolean focus;

        // Does the object have focus
        @Override
        public boolean hasFocus()
        {
            return this.focus;
        }

        // Set the focus
        public void setFocus(boolean f)
        {
            this.focus = f;
        }
    }

    // Removes focus from all labels
    private void removeFocus()
    {
        hostessPodiumLbl.setBorder(null);
        hostessPodiumLbl.setFocus(true);
        roundTableLbl.setBorder(null);
        roundTableLbl.setFocus(true);
        squareTableLbl.setBorder(null);
        squareTableLbl.setFocus(true);
        rectangularTableLbl.setBorder(null);
        rectangularTableLbl.setFocus(true);
        tableForTwoLbl.setBorder(null);
        tableForTwoLbl.setFocus(true);
        boothLbl.setBorder(null);
        boothLbl.setFocus(true);
        buffettBarLbl.setBorder(null);
        buffettBarLbl.setFocus(true);
        toiletPaperDispenserLbl.setBorder(null);
        toiletPaperDispenserLbl.setFocus(true);
        toiletLbl.setBorder(null);
        toiletLbl.setFocus(true);
        towelDispenserLbl.setBorder(null);
        towelDispenserLbl.setFocus(true);
        wasteBasketLbl.setBorder(null);
        wasteBasketLbl.setFocus(true);
        bathroomSinkLbl.setBorder(null);
        bathroomSinkLbl.setFocus(true);
        ovenLbl.setBorder(null);
        ovenLbl.setFocus(true);
        rangeLbl.setBorder(null);
        rangeLbl.setFocus(true);
        counterTopLbl.setBorder(null);
        counterTopLbl.setFocus(true);
        fridgeLbl.setBorder(null);
        fridgeLbl.setFocus(true);
        freezerLbl.setBorder(null);
        freezerLbl.setFocus(true);
        kitchenSinkLbl.setBorder(null);
        kitchenSinkLbl.setFocus(true);
        dishwasherLbl.setBorder(null);  
        dishwasherLbl.setFocus(true);
    }
}
```

I don't have much experience at all with GUIs in general so it's a wonder I got this far.  Has anyone ever worked on something like this?  Any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Frederic!  I'm still new here so I don't know much about the tags.

Comment: 1) Why you can't write your `mouseClicked` method in next way `removeFocus();((RLabel)e.getSource()) .setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));((RLabel)e.getSource()).setFocus(true);`?! It's shorter as minimum! 2) As you store Images with cost and name, maybe you convert your images to images without name and cost, and this parameters add as JLabels to Images?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean about the mouseClicked event.  Yeah, I agree that is a lot of code there.  I will make your changes as it's a lot better.  I just didn't know how to code it like that.

Comment: I assume since the JLabels are currently using ImageIcons to store the image, that when I make a copy of them that I can just assign a new ImageIcon to the label based on which label was selected.  I guess I need to make the copies work first.

Comment: For cheking use `System.out.println();` or Debugger, not this code! Code that I post solve your problems because you call 3 same methods for all labels(RLabel). Change it in 3 lines ;). Are your Images contain name and cost, or you add programatically?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the repeated code.  I changed it.  I think I might add a variable to store which label is currently selected and then I can clean up the removeFocus() method.  

And yes, my images I made in Photoshop and they have the prices stored on them.  They also are of different sizes than what will fit in the panel so some of them are bigger and some are smaller.  I just made them all uniform so the user can easily see them on the scroll bar.  The actual images vary in size though.

Comment: As I recommended you cut all Strings from your images, and add cost and names under Jlabel which contains Images. You got 3 JLabel instead one, in this case you can drag what you want. It really proper way

Answer (score 0):

I think it's answer for you.

1) Get all your Images and cut from they cost and name data.

2) Add your components with help of LayoutManager, I think [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is suitable for that purpose.

3) Add your Image with help of(JLabel) then  add JLabel with name property under the first and next add JLabel with cost.

If you do all in that way you can drag only Images without additional information, it solve problem with different images for one Entity.

As recommendation:

1) Change your `mouseClicked` method in next way:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    removeFocus();
    ((RLabel)e.getSource()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
    ((RLabel)e.getSource()).setFocus(true);
}
```

It clears method from duplication code.

2) instead of using `setBounds()` method use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) it do all work with component size.

3) Never do that `setLayout(null);`

4) Split your constructor method for some simple and clear methods. It's really looks awful.

Comment: I use the null layout just because I am using full screen layout and it's not resizeable.  So the components won't need to be relocated.  It's just easier for me to place objects in specific spots like that.

Also, I am not sure if removing the text from the images will help.  The objects are different sizes from what is in that scroll pane.  For instance, a toilet paper dispenser is really small on the floor plan, so I had to make it larger on the item list so the user can see what they are choosing.  It's the same way for all the objects.  They are either blown up or shrunk.

Comment: In this case you can try to write subclass of 'imageicon' like a wrapper with 2 images and returns first or second by flag. Flag will be switched if you start to drag label . Or you can write you own label with dnd listener and returns new instance at drag start